# Neo4j cypher query builder for PHP

Tags: neo4j, cypher

It's been a while and currently there is no query builder for neo4j in PHP. I don't whether this is intentional or they gonna release this feature in the future? I'm gonna start one and just wanted to shout out and kick off a discussion before doing it.

Answer (score 0):

Same issues here. I have started to work on a Symfony2/3 bundle for my own projects and wanted to make it available for everyone.

Work is pretty much on the way but there is no release yet. If anyone wants to contribute, it'd be great...

See `https://github.com/adadgio/graph-bundle/blob/master/ORM/Cypher.php`

Here https://github.com/adadgio/graph-bundle

List of currently supported statements would be here: `https://github.com/adadgio/graph-bundle/blob/master/Tests/ORM/CypherTest.php`

Answer (score 0):

You can use github.com/go1com/neo4j_builder.

Answer (score 0):

Probably the most complete Cypher query builder for PHP is currently `wikibasesolutions/php-cypher-dsl`. It is stable, well tested, and implements nearly all features of Cypher. Furthermore, it is type-safe and implemented in such a way that IDEs offer relevant hints on how to continue your query.

You can download it through [Packagist](https://packagist.org/packages/wikibase-solutions/php-cypher-dsl), or view the [GitHub repository](https://github.com/WikibaseSolutions/php-cypher-dsl).

Full disclose: I am the author of `php-cypher-dsl`.